# How to reset Read write permission in AWS lightsail for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ftp

Have a look at this image : http://prntscr.com/iadnrl

Adding new theme to Wordpress after deleting all tables and data. While activating new theme getting this mentioned error of connection FTP.

I **already tried following commands , seems does not worked.**

- `sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs`
- `sudo passwd bitnamiftp`

Hosting is on AWS Lightsail. 
Please share your views.

Answer (score 0):

> TAKE A BACKUP BEFORE RUNNING THESE COMMANDS. I am not responsible for any error.

The following command worked for me. Make sure to replace the `bitnami` to the proper user.

Change to proper permissions of all **files**:

```
find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs -type f -exec chown bitnami: {} \;
```

Change to proper permissions of all **folders**:

```
find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs -type d -exec chown bitnami: {} \;
```

Comment: Tried, but no luck .  Most files from and folder said , operation not permitted